# Android App Deleted

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new in android. Recently I've uploaded an app on google play but didn't put ads in it (I considered that I'll do it and just update the app).

The problem is that when I was trying to fix some errors in my app code(I'm using eclipse) I tried to delete it from eclipse and import it back. I checked "Copy projects into workspace" and I have no idea why, the whole project has been deleted.

The files are still there but they all have 0 bytes. I still have the .apk also.

Is there anyway to recover the files or the codes back? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some lessons are learnt the hard way!
Backup your project repeatedly if you are working individually.

You need to use some Memory Recovery Tools, until you find one, do not do operations like Disk De-Fragmentation, Disk Clean up etc. Delete no other files. Doing this may overrite the sectors of your HD, making it even more worse. Find a recovery tool, and hope for the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can recover the code. If you have the .apk try using dex2jar. Next time be sure that you backup all your projects!

Comment: Dex2jar worked fine. After watching a tutorial on youtube I could recover a part of the code. Thanks!